# Preventing narrowing conversion when using std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    X(std::initializer_list<int> list) { std::cout << "list" << std::endl; }
    X(float f) { std::cout << "float" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    int x { 1.0f };
    X a(1);     // float (implicit conversion)
    X b{1};     // list
    X c(1.0f);  // float
    X d{1.0f};  // list (narrowing conversion) ARG!!!

    // warning: narrowing conversion of '1.0e+0f' from 'float' to 'int'
    // inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
}
```

Is there any other way of removing `std::initializer_list` from an overload list (i.e., making the non-list ctors more favorable) instead of using the ()-initialization, or at least prohibiting narrowing conversion to happen (apart from turning warning into error)?

I was using http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ compiler which uses GCC 4.8.

Comment: Good question, +1. But it's an interesting class which can be constructed from an arbitrary amount of integers or exactly one floating point number.

Comment: @Angew: I would avoid judging reduced test cases too eagerly, for example did you know about [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution) ? Not exactly identical, obviously, but still showing off why it could be desirable.

Comment: Herb Sutter covered this recently.  Since you used brace-initialization, the initializer-list version is preferred.  If you want the float constructor, you must use parentheses.  See examples (d) and (e) here:  http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, a program containing a narrowing conversion in a brace list initializer is **ill-formed**. I am not sure why the compiler just gives you a warning, but it definitely should issue an error here (FWIW, [Clang does that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f4b28ee252709be69fa3e506e6646409-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336)).

Also notice, that this is a narrowing (and therefore illegal) conversion as well:

```
int x { 1.0f }; // ERROR! Narrowing conversion required
```

Per paragraph 8.5.4/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> — If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1). [...]
>
> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements [...]
>
> — Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`, [...]
>
> — Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated
> and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). **If a narrowing conversion (see
> below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed**. [...]

To be more precise, the Standard only says that a "diagnostic" is required in this case, and a warning is a diagnostic, so the compiler's behavior is conforming - but I believe emitting an error would be a better behavior.

Comment: Narrowing conversions now apply to C-arrays ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c45787e3e4535b20bcc37c6d62a9e074-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc)). Therefore, making narrowing conversions an error could break existing code.

Comment: @Morwenn: That's true, but in this case we are not initializing an aggregate

Comment: @AndyProwl They probably just made a general `-Wnarrowing` and did not want to bother having things like `-Wcarraysnarrowing` and `-Waggregatesnarrowing`.

Comment: @Morwenn: Perhaps that's the case. FWIW, [Clang rejects it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f4b28ee252709be69fa3e506e6646409-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336)

Comment: @Morwenn it is the opposite of general: there are stricter rules for this particular context, which is new in C++11.

Comment: @AndyProwl, building existing code with `g++ -std=c++0x` before narrowing conversions were downgraded to warnings caused previously well-formed (and sometimes provably correct! [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5ccdde12b17339c8a9a8a924381b5503-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc)) code to suddenly stop compiling. Narrowing conversions caused the majority of C++11 porting issues for at least two huge firms I know of, and my own experience in smaller code bases was similar. If you want an error use `-pedantic-errors` or `-Werror=narrowing`

Comment: @juanchopanza: You're right, I just don't think code should be modified to make this an error or circumvent the rules of overload resolution, it's just going to be a bigger mess IMO. I believe the problem has to be solved at the compiler level (perhaps passing proper flags)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: All right, I didn't know about those big porting issues. Thank you for explaining

Comment: I see now where the standard allows ill-formed code as long as it gives diagnostics, but it clearly labels such behaviour as an extension to the language, and as such, allowing narrowing here is non-portable at best, and it's likely only a matter of time before GCC makes this an error by default. In the mean-time, forcing an error is the most reasonable thing you can do in the OP's case.

Comment: Rick is right: The standard doesn't allow ill-formed code, ill-formed means ill-formed. The term we often use for what GCC is doing here is that GCC has a *conforming extension* -- it emits a diagnostic as required, then continues on to give meaning to a program that has no legal meaning in ISO C++.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a compiler error. You should be getting an error instead of a warning. Brace initialization should never implicitly narrow.

From the standard (§ 8.5.4)

> ```
> struct B {
>   B(std::initializer_list<int>);
> };
> B b1 { 1, 2 }; // creates initializer_list<int> and calls constructor
> B b2 { 1, 2.0 }; // error: narrowing
> ```

Comment: The standard requires a diagnostic, so issuing a warning is conforming. You can use `-pedantic-errors` or `-Werror=narrowing` if you want an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with `std::enable_if`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
    template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value>::type>
    X(std::initializer_list<T>) { std::cout << "list" << std::endl; }
    X(float) { std::cout << "float" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    X a(1);     // float (implicit conversion)
    X b{1};     // list
    X c(1.0f);  // float
    X d{1.0f};  // float (yay)
}
```

Works on both [g++4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d82be774dcbf2c3bd97cb35da92f8b1a-b1fba5242d36d8fdaa89f56dd07dd250) and clang 3.2

Comment: `enable_if` is how you remove it from the list of candidates, but I don't think `is_same` is the right condition here (it prevents widening as well as narrowing).

Comment: You are right, of course, I didn't think of that. I think `std::is_same<typename std::common_type<T,int>::type,int>::value` would work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Wno-c++11-narrowing` to turn off the errors:

Here's a sample test program:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct foo {
    int32_t a;
};

void foo(int64_t val) {
    struct foo A = { val };
}
```

Compile with clang++-3.8 with just `-std=c++11`, we get the stated error:

[image]

Add `-Wno-c++11-narrowing`, golden silence :-)

[image]

Of course, the narrowing issue might come back to bite you later, but it might occasionally be easier to delay the technical debt pain till later.  ymmv :-)