# Prevent converting uint64_t to uint16_t

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

Why does the following code compile in clang++?

Are there any c++ flags to prevent this from happening - I would like the compiler to throw an error because I am passing a std::uint64_t as an argument to a function that accepts std::uint16_t.

```
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

void foo(uint16_t x) {
}

int main() {
    uint64_t x = 10000;
    foo(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Narrowing conversions are permitted in C++, and unsigned narrowing conversions are well-defined

Comment: Adding `-Werror=conversion` will cause your example to not compile.

Comment: ..or just `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`

Comment: @JohnBollinger Simple: It's error-prone. An `uint16_t` and an `uint64_t` are *different types*. These implicit conversions caused enough headaches. I'd recommend to *always* set the warning levels high enough to cover such things.

Answer (score 33):

you can delete a function in c++11

```
void foo(uint64_t) = delete;
```

it works by adding the signature at function overload resolution, and if it was a better match, an error occurs. You can also make it generic to allow only you original signature

```
template <class T> void foo( T&& ) = delete;
```

Comment: How is this responsive to the question posed?

Comment: he asked how to prevent it from happening and this will effectively prevent it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The given program would fail to compile with this added, would it not?

Comment: because it is what he ask, the compiler to throw an error if someone provide an uint64 to the function receiving a uint16

Comment: He *first* asked why his code compiles, which is not addressed in this answer.  Fair enough, though, that this does answer the second part.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `enable_if` as a SFINAE return parameter

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, uint16_t>::value>::type 
foo(T x) 
{
    std::cout << "uint16_t" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, uint16_t>::value>::type 
foo(T x)
{
    std::cout << "rest" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    uint16_t x = 10000;
    uint64_t y = 100000;
    foo(x); // picks up uint16_t version
    foo(y); // picks up anything else, but NOT uint16_t
    return 0;
}
```

In this way you can have one overload that deals specifically with `uint16_t`, and another overload that deals with anything else.

Comment: This is good but it also prevents widening conversions (as does the other answer). It'd be nice if the function could accept `uint8_t` values for example, and maybe even literals whose value fits in `uint16_t`.  Someone suggested using `std::common_type` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16945743/1505939) however I don't think that would work for `uint16_t` because of integer promotion to `int`

Comment: @MattMcNabb hmm, this seems a bit more tricky, and it is actually interesting: how to accept anything that "fits" into the parameter. Well, there is a "way": brute force, specify the template explicitly, like `foo<int16_t>(x);`. Not very pretty though.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that would allow widening conversions and prevent the narrowing ones:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

void foo(uint16_t x) {
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof(uint16_t) < sizeof(T)>::type foo(const T& t) = delete;

int main() {
    uint64_t x = 10000;
    uint16_t y = 10000;
    uint8_t z = 100;
    // foo(x); // ERROR: narrowing conversion
    foo(y); // OK: no conversion
    foo(z); // OK: widening conversion
    return 0;
}
```

In case you'd also like to disallow calls with arguments of signed types (conversions between signed and unsigned types are not "lossless"), you could use the following declaration instead:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

void foo(uint16_t x) {
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(uint16_t) < sizeof(T)) ||
                        (std::is_signed<T>::value != std::is_signed<uint16_t>::value)
                       >::type
foo(const T& t) = delete;

int main() {
    uint64_t u64 = 10000;
    uint16_t u16 = 10000;
    uint8_t u8 = 100;
    int64_t s64 = 10000;
    int16_t s16 = 10000;
    int8_t s8 = 100; 

    //foo(u64); // ERROR: narrowing conversion
    foo(u16); // OK: no conversion
    foo(u8); // OK: widening conversion
    //foo(s64); // ERROR: narrowing conversion AND signed/unsigned mismatch
    //foo(s16); // ERROR: signed/unsigned mismatch
    //foo(s8); // ERROR: signed/unsigned mismatch

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to allow widening conversions, but forbid narrowing conversions, perhaps:

```
void foo(uint16_t x) {
}

template <class T>
void foo( const T&& t )
{
    return foo(uint16_t{t});
}
```

This forces all types except `uint16_t` itself to go through list-initialization, which forbids narrowing conversions.

It doesn't work so well if you already have a number of overloads, though.

Comment: Unfortunately narrowing is not required to result in an error, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28466069/3093378. For example, this works: http://ideone.com/DHqBYL . Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @vsoftco "if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to `T`, the program is ill-formed", from 8.5.4

Comment: @Barry yes, it is ill formed, however the compiler is not required to emit an error. And in fact compiles the program.

Comment: @vsoftco: If you configure your build settings to continue when an ill-formed program is encountered, you get what you ask for.  A conforming compiler will never be silent about this, and most will error unless specifically configured not to.

Comment: Yes, indeed, you get an warning with `-Wall -Wextra` on g++. However I found it extremely odd that without enabling warnings you don't get any diagnostic, since I was sure that the program won't even compile.

Comment: @vsoftco: If you get no diagnostic, then your compiler is not a C++11 compiler.  This is explained in the question you already linked, which you participated in, so you must already know that.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am however surprised why you don't get any diagnostic whatsoever on http://ideone.com/DHqBYL ?

Comment: @vsoftco: It's because ideone doesn't show compiler output unless compilation fails.  They also break links all the time, in violation of their own FAQ.  Best solution, switch to rextester or coliru

Comment: Didn't know about the broken links, thanks. I am compiling however on my machine, with g++5.1, -Wall -Wextra, and nothing, no diagnostic whatsoever. Not [on Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) either, which shows the compiler output and uses implicitly `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Interestingly, using "normal" reference instead of rvalue reference (`void foo(const T& t)` instead of `void foo(const T&& t)`) in function argument type would make GCC emit a warning even at default warning level, without `-Wall` set (tested with GCC 4.9.2). Won't make it emit an error though.

Answer (score 4):

Although most answers here are technically correct, you will most likely not want the behaviour to apply only to this function, so a "code level" solution that you have to write for each of these conversion cases is probably not what you want.

On a "project/compilation level" you can add this flag to warn you about these conversions:

```
-Wconversion
```

or if you prefer directly treat them as errors:

```
-Werror=conversion
```

Comment: Note that this won't warn (tested in GCC 4.9.2) about conversion from signed `int16_t` to unsigned `uint16_t`, which too can cause invalid value to be passed into function. You can add `-Wsign-conversion` (or`-Werror=sign-conversion`) to detect changes in signedness.