# Understanding when checks happen in () and {} initization through class constructors

Tags: c++, initialization, brackets

From what I understand, `{}` is a way to initialize variables with some "safety" advantages over other methods, such as forbidding narrowing:

```cpp
int some_int_a = 1.2;  // narrows
int some_int_b (1.2);  // narrows
int some_int_c {1.2};  // does NOT compile, cannot narrow
```

So far so good. The thing I recently discovered, that I do not understood fully, is when does this sort of check happen? For example, in the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class ExClass{
    private:
        const int i;
    public:
        ExClass(int i=0): i{i} {
            // needed even if empty
        }
        void print(void){
            std::cout << "const int i = " << i << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{

    ExClass ex_a (2.3);  // narrows! this was surprising to me, I (probably naively)
                         // expected i{i} in the constructor to forbid this.
    ex_a.print();

    ExClass ex_b {2.3};  // does not compile
    ex_b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I suppose this means that in the case of `ex_a`, first an intermediate `int` is created fully with a narrowing conversion, then this intermediate `int` is used to bracket-initialize `i` in the constructor. While in the second case, the intermediate `int` cannot be bracket-initialized with a conflicting input, is that right?

Is there a way to write things in such a way that there is no "intermediate" narrowing, so that the class bracket initialization detects the faulty input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that the constructor:

```
ExClass(int i=0): i{i}
```

Takes an `int` parameter, and narrowing here:

```
ExClass ex_a (2.3);
```

is fine. Once you are in the contructor, `i` is an `int` (the parameter, not the member). Hence there is no narrowing in `i{i}` (it is `int` to `int`). You do get [the error](https://godbolt.org/z/Pxcvf7) when you change your constructor to:

```
ExClass(double i=0): i{i} { }
```

Because now there is actually narrowing in `i{i}`.

Note that gcc only issues [a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/5ofWW8) with default settings and needs `-pedantic-errors` to recognize it as error. Thanks to Remy for pointing out that it actually is an error, not a warning.

Comment: Thanks, so that confirms what I was thinking. Do you know if there is a(mother) way so as to avoid the first narrowing, ie to transmit the initialisation 'right through' to the constructor, without the intermediate narrowing?

Comment: @Zorglub29 there is no "intermediate narrowing" the narrowing happens here `ExClass ex_a (2.3);` and here `ExClass ex_b {2.3};` from that on it is all integers and in the first case narrowing is allowed and in the latter not. Why there is only a warning and not an error when you defer the narrowing to the initializer list (as in my example) I don't know

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug, or at least a cop-out. Per cppreference ([here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)), narrowing conversions are not allowed in a brace-init-list, even when used in a constructor's member initialization list. So `i{i}` *should not* compile when initializing an `int` with a `double` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16939798/65863)). GCC does allow this, though. But clang does not ("*error: type 'double' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list*")

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. Another case where gccs defaults are a bit odd. With `-pedantic-errors` it emits the error.

Comment: Aaah, so then do you mean @RemyLebeau that I was right to be surprised? ^^

Comment: @Zorglub29 the warning / error issue is about the example of replacing your constructor with `ExClass(double i=0): i{i} { }`. In your `()` case there should not be any error

Answer (score 1):

Brace initialization (since C++11) prevents narrowing. As [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) states under *Narrowing conversions*:

> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by
> prohibiting the following:
>
> - conversion from a floating-point type to an integer type
> - conversion from a long double to double or to float and conversion from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression
>   and overflow does not occur
> - conversion from an integer type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value can be stored
>   exactly in the target type
> - conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, except where
>   source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in
>   the target type
> - conversion from a pointer type or pointer-to-member type to bool (since C++20)

So prefer brace initialization over the alternatives.

Comment: Yes, the surprising thing for me is how 'intermediate' narrowing happened...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to write things in such a way that there is no "intermediate" narrowing, so that the class bracket initialization detects the faulty input?

You can make the constructor take a template parameter so it takes on the type of whatever the caller passes in, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class ExClass{
    private:
        const int i;
    public:
        template<typename T>
        ExClass(T i=T{}): i{i} {
            // needed even if empty
        }
        void print(void){
            std::cout << "const int i = " << i << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{

    ExClass ex_a (2.3);  // should not compile!
    ex_a.print();

    ExClass ex_b {2.3};  // should not compile!
    ex_b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, GCC allows this narrowing by default, issuing a *warning* rather than an error (use `-pedantic-errors` to force an error):

> warning: narrowing conversion of 'i' from 'double' to 'int' [-Wnarrowing]

Clang issues an error, though:

> error: type 'double' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]

Comment: That looks very nice, many thanks. So then it is a tradeoff between making things safer this way and typing a bit of extra magics :) .

Answer (score -1):

The debugger would probably show you this very quickly!
Look at what you are doing:
if(ExClass(next) == false || opening_brackets_stack.empty() == false)

What is the type of ExClass when you try to compare it with a close bracket

Hint: think about when you create each new instance of a Bracket. Are they all brackets?
Are they all open brackets?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about.