# What are the rules for integral promotions in initialization lists and is this a false positive warning in GCC or rather C++ limitation?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gcc-warning, uniform-initialization

In the below code we essentially assign the same value to 4 unsigned char variables in 4 different ways - but one of them *using the initialization list* issues a warning:

`warning: narrowing conversion of '~(int)a' from 'int' to 'unsigned char' [-Wnarrowing]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    unsigned char a = 0b10101010u;      

    unsigned char b = ~a;      
    
    unsigned char c(~a);

    auto test = std::vector<unsigned char>{};
    test.emplace_back(~a);

    auto test2 = std::vector<unsigned char>{~a}; // THIS IS THE LINE GCC COMPLAINS ABOUT

    std::cout << std::hex 
        << size_t(b) << std::endl
        << size_t(c) << std::endl
        << size_t(test[0]) << std::endl
        << size_t(test2[0]) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why?
Is this a bug in GCC? A language limitation?

You can play with the code here :)
https://godbolt.org/z/To5ezrecc

Comment: The answer to why there is a warning or error is in this case, "because the language says so". In list initialization, narrowing conversions are not permitted.

Comment: This may answer your question: [Preventing narrowing conversion when using std::initializer_list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16939798/7582247)

Answer (score 2):

The warning is correct. In list-initialization (i.e. with braces) narrowing conversions are ill-formed, also in initialization of elements of a `std::initializer_list`. GCC is rather permissive here, since it *only* produces a warning instead of a hard error (as for example Clang does).

In `~a` integral promotions are applied to `a`. In this case `a` is promoted to `int`, since it can represent all values of `unsigned char`.

Therefore `~a` also has type `int` and because it is also not a constant expression, the conversion required to `unsigned char` for the `std::initializer_list<unsigned char>` constructor parameter is narrowing.

If you really intend to do the narrowing conversion cast explicitly:

```
auto test2 = std::vector<unsigned char>{static_cast<unsigned char>(~a)};
```

The same applies to other initialization methods using list-initialization (braces):

```
unsigned char d{~a};
unsigned char e = {~a};
```

Both are ill-formed as well.